# Navbar creating empty space down and above when adding logo

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav

I want to make the navbar with logo. but its creating empty space below when adding height or width.
is there any css property I can use?

it does not look good like this.

[this is navbar without logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIi4H.png)

[this is navbar with logo:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MWqK.png)

html:

```
<section id="header">
  <a class="name" href="#header"
    >SYNCC
    <img
      src="images/logo.png"
      alt=""
      height="90"

      class="logo-png"
  /></a>
  <div> 
    <ul id="navbar">
      <li><a class="active" href="#hero">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#feature">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#footer">Contact</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#carouselExampleControls"
          ><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i
        ></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

css:

```
  #header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px 80px;
  /* background: #e3e6f3; */
  background: #E5E6EE;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  z-index: 999;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 30%;
}

#navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

#navbar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}

.name {
  font-family: "DynaPuff", cursive;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}

.name:hover,
.name a {
  color: #088178;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.name a::after,
.name a:hover {
  content: "";
  width: 30%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #088178;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 20px;
}
#navbar li a:hover,
#navbar li a.active {
  color: #088178;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

#navbar li a.active::after,
#navbar li a:hover::after {
  content: "";
  width: 30%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #088178;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

tried using display : block;
I tried several ways to fix it.
any other way  can use to make it correct.

Answer (score -1):

Usally when this happens to me, I will just add `top:--px;` or `bottom:--px;` accordingly to make them line up.